# OPENJSON stored procedure [1,2,3,4,5]

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this data passed from my repo [1,2,3,4,5], it is a `List<int>` converted to a json string.

Now I want to insert it into the database. How should I write my query?

```
INSERT INTO CommitteeMember     
    SELECT 
        @committeeID,       
        *         // how to call it?    
    FROM 
        OPENJSON(@membersJson) AS json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want something like below:

```
CREATE TABLE CommitteeMember(committeeID INT, memberID INT);

DECLARE @membersJSON NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[1,2,3,4,5]';
DECLARE @commiteeID INT = 10;

INSERT INTO CommitteeMember(committeeId, memberId)
SELECT @commiteeID AS committeeId,value AS memberId
FROM OPENJSON(@membersJSON);

SELECT *
FROM CommitteeMember;
```

**[Dbfiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c0031610d11227bb2068720b51925a57)**

Comment: wow thanks, its the most usefull answer I found today. +1 for dbfiddle. never see this thing exists